# 'inaccessible due to its proctecion level'?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a singleton to save the players score they just got and pass it to the next scene, but I'm getting an error: `Inaccessible due its protection level`.

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Score instance { get; private set;}
    public int score = 0;

    void Awake()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("increaseScore", 1, 1);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        score++;
        // Set the score text.
        guiText.text = "Score: " + score;
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

That's the code for where the playing happens in scene 1.

```
public class endScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    void getScore()
    {
        Score.instance.Update();
    }
}
```

This is where I'm calling it in the next scene.

EDIT:

```
public class endScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    void getScore()
    {
        Score.instance.Update();
    guiText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }
}
```

It does'nt recognise the `+ score`? I thought singletons grabbed all the variables from the set instance?

Comment: Please show the *exact* error message, including where it occurs.

Comment: endScore.cs(8,32): error CS0122: `Score.Update()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: The methods are not public, that is why. Try: public void Update ().

Comment: Right. Now it's pretty clear: `Update()` is a private method. You possibly want to make it `protected`.

Comment: Additionally, please pay more attention to formatting your posts in future. Use spaces instead of tabs, and use the preview to see what it'll look like.

Comment: Oh, and this isn't a singleton, by the way. You should read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions on how to ask better questions. You've currently got 4 questions, two of which have -2 votes... if this continues, you're likely to get an automated question ban.

Comment: Ohhh! I did'nt realise that had such an impact! Yeah its gone Thanks guys, you just saved me hours sitting here stressing over what it could be!

Comment: what? oh great thats why it was down voted. I really dont want that ill check it out. Any ideas how to solve the edit jon?

Comment: If someone solves your question, consider upvoting and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the method `Update` of the class `Score` to public so that it can be accessed by object calling an instance of `Score`

Change it to Public to make it more accessible or perhaps better Protected to make it less accessible than public but more than private ([read more about that here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx))

```
Public void Update ()
{
    score++;
    // Set the score text.
    guiText.text = "Score: " + score;
    instance = this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't realize this, `Update` in Unity is a method called once per frame, for each `MonoBehavior` class script. You're really not supposed to call it yourself!